# Move a number to the left in a string recursive

Tags: java, recursion

The task is to shift a number within a string to the beginning of the string with a recursion. Only one number is always contained within the string. So if I feed "ba3nana" to the code it should return "3banana". Did some recursive tasks already but this one I am stuck on. I tried I guess already 50 different combinations but so far my code only returns "banana3" so I go the opposite way with my number. I understand that this code moves every number to the right but still cannot figure out the right combination to get the output with the number on the left. If I shift things around everything gets reversed to become "3ananab"

The call of the method looks like this:

```
System.out.println(shiftDigitLeft("ba3nana"));
```

This is the code so far which returns banana3:

```
private static String shiftDigitLeft(String text) {
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text.charAt(0) >= '\u0030' && text.charAt(0) <= '\u0039') {
                return shiftDigitLeft(text.substring(1)) + text.charAt(0);
            } else {
                return text.charAt(0) + shiftDigitLeft(text.substring(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could show me how it's done propperly, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same but starting with the last character and moving backwards:

```
private static String shiftDigitLeft(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        return text;
    } else {
        if (text.charAt(text.length() - 1) >= '\u0030' && text.charAt(text.length() - 1) <= '\u0039') {
            return text.charAt(text.length() - 1) + shiftDigitLeft(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
        } else {
            return shiftDigitLeft(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1)) + text.charAt(text.length() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Seeing it now makes me understand what I did wrong but for sure I would have needed a lot more days to get this result.